# Need to categorized one column with respect to another Column

Tags: r

I want to categorized one column with respect to another Column.
The question is what percentage of car is red for age group
below 35
36-48
49 above

Data is

```
AGE RED_CAR freq
16  yes 2
17  yes 1
18  yes 2
19  yes 1
21  yes 1
22  yes 8
23  yes 4
24  yes 13
25  yes 5
26  yes 7
27  yes 4
28  yes 5
29  yes 5
30  yes 9
```

Kindly help

Comment: your data does not illustrate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem.  My preferred way is using the cut function and tapply.

Here is some sample data:

```
AGE<-c(16:19, 21:30)
RED_CAR<-rep(c("yes", "no"), 7)
freq<-c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 8, 4, 13, 5, 7, 4, 5, 5, 9)
df<-data.frame(AGE, RED_CAR, freq)
```

Here is the solution:

```
#define the age breaks, include a low and high limit to include all cases
# in this case breaks are at 17 and 48
agebreaks<-c(0, 17, 48, 99)

#tapply to sum the counts, includes the filtering for RED_CAR==yes
countbyage<-tapply(df$freq[df$RED_CAR=="yes"], cut(df$AGE[df$RED_CAR=="yes"], breaks= agebreaks), sum)

#divide bin counts by total count
percentage<-countbyage/sum(df$freq)
```

The package dplyr has a few functions as group_by, tally and count which would also work.  Basic analysis base R is fine, but for large dataset dplyr is a better solution.